# WebView opens link, then opens in browser

Tags: android, webview

Friends noticed that the webview my page loads but when you click the link it opens the navigated and I wanted to be loaded only within the webview, I would like min help?

I did the project below:

http://karthiktechfreak.blogspot.com.br/2015/07/profesional-android-webview-application.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what your question is, but here is a Webview app that will work.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startWebView();

        //Now, use webView.loadUrl(String url) whenever you want to load a website  
    }

    void startWebView(){
        webView     = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"     
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you friend for your reply but how to integrate your code in the code
MainActivity on the site above?

For I put your code in the tutorial MainActivity and gave error